# How to sort pandas column base on a specified order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
index  life_stage
1      Early Childhood
2      Birth
3      Infancy
...
```

The `life_stage` column is not ordered correctly and I cannot rely on alphabetical order.

The correct order would be

```
Birth
Infancy
Early Childhood
```

Is it possible to sort the life stage column according to an order that I specify in Pandas?

Comment: Please share what order you want to use and thus expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's convert "life_stage" into an ordered categorical column using `pd.Categorical`:

```
df['life_stage'] = pd.Categorical(
    df['life_stage'], 
    categories=['Birth', 'Infancy', 'Early Childhood'], 
    ordered=True
)
```

Note the order in which I specify the categories to `pd.Categorical`. Now, call `sort_values` using `life_stage`:

```
df.sort_values(by=['life_stage'])

   index       life_stage
2      1            Birth
1      2          Infancy
0      3  Early Childhood
```

---

For reference, sorting "life_stage" alphabetically gets you

```
   index       life_stage
2      1            Birth
0      3  Early Childhood   # wrong!
1      2          Infancy
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want `pd.Categorical` with order:

```
s = pd.Categorical(['Infancy', 'Birth', 'Early Childhood'],
               categories=['Birth', 'Infancy', 'Early Childhood'],
               ordered=True)
s.sort_values()
```

Output:

```
[Birth, Infancy, Early Childhood]
Categories (3, object): [Birth < Infancy < Early Childhood]
```